# Adapter label and electricity consumption

Tags: power-consumption

My surveilance cam label states 5==1A. I am not an electrician, but is it right to say that based on tha label, to compute for Power (watts) consumed by the device:

1A x 120 volts = 120 watts

For electricity consumption:

120 watts x 24 hours = 2,880 watt-hrs per day
2,880 watt-hrs per day / 1000 = 2.88 kwh per day
2.88 kwh per day x 31 days = 89.28 kwh per month
89.28 kwh per month x $.10 per kwh = $8.928 per month

Does that mean that I am spending $8.92 per month for a small camera?

Thanks

Comment: First of all I don't understand what `5==1A` means and how you concluded 120V from there. Second, it is the *maximum* rating.

Comment: No, but you probably spend 8$ a year, and xbox costs 14$ just to have it in off mode

Answer (score 6):

I think you are confusing the symbol for dc current (from [electrical-symbols.com](https://www.electrical-symbols.com/electric-electronic-symbols/electric-current-symbols.htm)):

[image]

with a double equals sign. Your camera must be supplied with 5V dc at a maximum current of 1A, so it consumes a maximum of 5W. Your monthly cost is pocket change.

Comment: But don't forget that the power supply has its own efficiency, which is lowee than 100%. Still, this shouldn't affect things too much.

Answer (score 5):

If your device (or adapter) states "5V=1A", then the device likely consumes 5 W of power, no more. These devices usually are supplied with AC-DC wall adapters. These adapters are NOT linear voltage dividers, they **convert** input power into output power, almost like an old magnetic-based transformer, just do it a bit differently. And they do this transformation with about 80% efficiency. Therefore if your load (webcam) uses 5 W, the AC-DC adapter will use 5/0.8 = 6.25 W at input. If the "primary AC-side" is 120 V, the whole setup will consume about 50-55 mA of current (6.25W/120V), not 1A as you suspect. Therefore you will be paying about 1/20 of your calculated $9/month, or just 45c per month.

Answer (score 2):

Extremely unlikely. Is it possible that it actually says "5V 1A" or similar? That would mean that the cam requires a supply of 5V that *can* supply 1A (but probably the cam uses nothing like that on average). in other words - it would be a spec for what the supply should be capable of, rather than of the actual usage (which is often not stated).

120W would be a crazy amount of power for a web cam. If you really want to know, you can buy fairly inexpensive ($20 or so) power meters that will measure actual power for you.